# My ad is not popping up, and I have put in place everything that adMob told me to

Tags: android, ads

I am testing out my app, and trying to put ads on it. I have added a test device, and loaded the add, but the add still does not show up. Does anyone know what is going on. Here is my code

MainActivity

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("device-id")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

xml

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: what does your Logcat say? it usually tells you if its trying to load the ad or not

Comment: It says ad finished loading, but I can't see an ad on the screen

Comment: ok so this happens when you have no ads to serve - or you have just started using admob. I think the `device-id` for your test device is probably wrong - try the emulator